# How do I print a message if a ValueError occurs?

Tags: valueerror

```
while answers_right < 3:

    ran_number_1 = random.randint(10, 99)
    ran_number_2 = random.randint(10, 99)
    solution = ran_number_1 + ran_number_2

    print(f"What is {ran_number_1} + {ran_number_2}?")
    user_answer = int(input("Your answer: "))


    if user_answer == solution:
        answers_right += 1
        print(f"Correct. You've gotten {answers_right} correct in a row.")
    elif user_answer != solution:
        answers_right = 0
        print(f"Incorrect. The expected answer is {solution}.")


if answers_right == 3:
    print("Congratulations! You've mastered addition.")
```

I want to add an additional if statement in case someone types string and return a message that says "Invalid Response" instead of the Traceback Error.

Comment: Use try and except block

Answer (score 0):

Use of Exception handling in python may be solve your Problem and you can also generate your own error class for particular condition.

```
if x < 3:
      raise Exception("Sorry, no numbers below 3")
```

## Use of throw and raise keyword you can generate your own error.

for more reference[link here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to solve this problem is to look at the error type in your traceback, and use a try/except block. It will say something like `TypeError: error stuff here` or `ValueError: error stuff also here`.

The way you do a try/except is to:

```
try:
    some_code()
    that_might()
    produce_an_error()
except some_error_type:
    do_stuff()
except_some_other_error_type:
    do_other_stuff()
```

So, to catch a ValueError and a TypeError, you might do:

```
try:
    buggy_code()
except ValueError:
    print("Woah, you did something you shouldn't have")
except TypeError:
    print("Woah, you did something ELSE you shouldn't have")
```

If you then want the traceback, you can add in a lone "raise" statement below the excepts. For example:

```
try:
    buggy_code()
except ValueError:
    print("Woah, you did something you shouldn't have")
    raise
except TypeError:
    print("Woah, you did something ELSE you shouldn't have")
    raise
```

Errors have evolved to be a lot more useful in modern times. They don't break the entire system anymore, and there are ways of handling them. Try/Except blocks like the above give you the tools to have code that only executes when a specific error or set of errors is raised.